# Order by multiple tables column

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to run a query which will order my data based on presence of values in another table's column if present, if no data exists in another column, it should order it by column present in current table.

Explanation:-

Members Table: Contains list of all members.

Messages Table: Stores chat conversation between two members

```
            From_ID is basically sender id

            To_ID is basically recipient id
```

If member 1002 logs into application i want to retrieve list of all users from the members table in an order that it should contain first those users with which member 1002 had recent conversation (send or receive) in messages table and then other users from member table.

Table: Members

```
id  name
1001    john
1002    vicky
1003    Joseph
1004    Donald
1005    David
1006    Ram
1007    Watson
1008    Jacob
1009    cathrine
```

Table: Messages

```
from_id to_id    date
1003    1009     21-01-2018
1007    1002     21-01-2018
1008    1001     02-01-2018
1002    1008     01-01-2018
```

```
select * 
from members 
where id = '1002' order by (messages????????);
```

Result: 
    input id    1002

```
Desired output:

    1007
    1008
    1001
    1003
    1004
    1005
    1006
    1009
```

Comment: What happens if `1003` joins to more than one message?  This isn't clear.

Comment: More I look at it, less I understand it. SELECT you wrote returns 1 row (Vicky), so - what's the purpose of the ORDER BY? Furthermore, it is usual that FROM is smaller than TO, while your example shows both directions (e.g. 1003 - 1009 vs. 1008 - 1001). I'm totally confused.

Comment: Not clear: Do you want to order MEMBERS on the basis of whether they have **sent** a message? **Received** a message? Or both? Given that your "sample query" selects from MEMBERS and filters on ID (presumably the primary key) it will only retrieve one row so what is the point of the ORDER BY clause anyway?  You are asking us to spend our time helping you, the least you can do is invest some of your time framing a different question.

Comment: I have updated my question with more explanation of what is desired. Kindly have a look.

Comment: Well that changed it quite a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want user 1002's recent conversation partners first. The easiest way to achieve this is to order by latest message date:

```
select *
from members m
where id <> 1002
order by 
(
  select max(ms.date) 
  from messages ms 
  where (ms.from_id = m.id and ms.to_id = 1002)
     or (ms.from_id = 1002 and ms.to_id = m.id)
) desc nulls last;
```

Comment: The OP wants to filter on a specific user so messages containing that user in, from or to, should come first and also note that user should not be part of the result.

Comment: @Joakim Danielson: You are right. Thanks for pointing this out. I've updated my answer accordingly.